# Source of data in Redshift tables

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am looking to find the data source of couple of Tables in Redshift. I have gone through all the stored procedures in Redshift instance. I couldn't find any stored procedure which populates these tables in Redshift. I have also checked the Data Migration Service and didn't see these tables are being migrated from RDS instance. However, the tables are updated regularly each day.

What would be the way to find how data is populated in those 2 tables? Is there any logs or system tables I can look in to?

Answer (score 0):

One place I'd look is `svl_statementtext`. That will pull any queries and utility queries that may be inserting or running copy jobs against that table. Just use a `WHERE text LIKE %yourtablenamehere%` and see what comes back.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVL_STATEMENTTEXT.html

Also check scheduled queries in the Redshift UI console.

Comment: Excellent suggestion by @dfundako.  However, this will only work if the table in question is internal to Redshift.  If the the table is external (Redshift Spectrum) then anything that can change S3 can change your table.  If the table is listed in SVV_EXTERNAL_TABLES the data lives in S3.

Comment: Thank you @dfundako. This was really helpful. The output returns a starttime and text column containing part of the query if the query is large. Using that starttime it was then easy to find the full query and the source stored procedure containing that query from the AWS redshift console query monitoring tab.